# Calling $http.delete but nothing happens

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm actually working on a webclient calling a REST service.
After my last question, the GET request is working now.
Now i want o implement a DEL request using angulars delete method.
In the following example is my service request implemented.

```
function ItemsService($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
}

ItemsService.prototype = {
    deleteFoo: function (id) {
        this.$http.delete('http://localhost:3001/posts/' + id)
          .then(function successCallback(response) {
              console.log("DEL send...");
              console.log(response.data);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
              console.log('Error');
          });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    ItemsService: ItemsService
}
```

I added a button on the webpage with `ng-click="$ctrl.deleteMe()"`.
The controller looks like the following example:

```
function Foo(ItemsService) {
    this.itemsService = ItemsService;
}

Foo.prototype = {
    deleteMe: function () {
        console.log('delete now');
        this.itemsService.deleteFoo(1).then(
            response => {
                console.log('gelöscht? ' + response);
            }
        );
    }
};
```

If i now click on the button, nothing happens. In the network trace log in the dev tools in the browser i can't see a DEL request.
To test this REST service request, i run the JSON Server tool on port 3001.
I testet the availability of the server with SOAPUI, it works, i see all the requests in the console.
But no request from my test webpage.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Same Origin Policy? Does the Javascript run on the port :3001 too?

Comment: `delete` is a reserved keyword in js. I don't think that you should assign a whole new `prototype`, but instead do `Foo.prototype.deleteMe = function..`

Comment: @devqon anyway, ng is [using it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete). But you might be right that it needs to be changed in the prototype.

Comment: The Prototype layout is from FountainJS.io. I'm working with an YeoMan project lkayout from it. Anywhere, i changed to deleteMe and nothing happens.

Comment: `$http` doesn't have `deleteFoo` method

Comment: sending a DELETE request wont do anything unless you implement it in your backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return

```
return this.$http.delete('http://localhost:3001/posts/' + id)
          .then(function successCallback(response) {
              console.log("DEL send...");
              console.log(response.data);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
              console.log('Error');
          });
```

Comment: Thanks. In an earlier version of my example i didi it, but the system does not send any requests... :(

Comment: when you click button first check if it works $ctrl.deleteMe() by console.log('works')

Comment: can you share your html also ?

Comment: The HTML is very simple. Only a button with the ng-click attribute above. Anyway i found out, that the port was the problem. 3001 was not free. changing it to 50000 the request was sent successfully.